# Consultas HQL(Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Estoy comenzando a utilizar la herramienta de mapeo **Hibernate** y con el fin de conocer y familiarizarme con esta tecnología estoy realizando algunas consultas mediante **HQL** pero no estoy de el todo seguro si la aproximación que le estoy dando es la correcta.

A continuación expondré mas detalladamente  toda la información que interviene en el proyecto con el fin de que dispongáis de la mayor información posible.

---

### Clase Deportistas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "deportista")
public class Deportistas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "codDeportista")
    private int codDeportista;

    @Column(name = "nombreDeportista", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(60)")
    private String nombreDeportista;

    @Column(name = "dniDeportista", columnDefinition = "CHAR(12)")
    private String dniDeportista;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "pais")
    private Paises pais;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Licencias licencia;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "codDeportista")
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<Medallas> medallas = new ArrayList<Medallas>();

    public Deportistas() {

    }

    public Deportistas(int codDeportista, String nombreDeportista, String dniDeportista, Paises pais,
            Licencias licencia) {
        super();
        this.codDeportista = codDeportista;
        this.nombreDeportista = nombreDeportista;
        this.dniDeportista = dniDeportista;
        this.pais = pais;
        this.licencia = licencia;
    }

    public int getCodDeportista() {
        return codDeportista;
    }

    public void setCodDeportista(int codDeportista) {
        this.codDeportista = codDeportista;
    }

    public String getNombreDeportista() {
        return nombreDeportista;
    }

    public void setNombreDeportista(String nombreDeportista) {
        this.nombreDeportista = nombreDeportista;
    }

    public String getDniDeportista() {
        return dniDeportista;
    }

    public void setDniDeportista(String dniDeportista) {
        this.dniDeportista = dniDeportista;
    }

    public Paises getPais() {
        return pais;
    }

    public void setPais(Paises pais) {
        this.pais = pais;
    }

    public Licencias getLicencia() {
        return licencia;
    }

    public void setLicencia(Licencias licencia) {
        this.licencia = licencia;
    }

}
```

---

### Clase Medallas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "medallas")
public class Medallas implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codDeportista")
    private Deportistas codDeportista;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "codPrueba")
    private Pruebas codPrueba;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "fechaMedallas")
    private Date fechaMedallas;

    @Column(name = "puestoDeportista", columnDefinition = "CHAR(1)")
    private String puestoDeportista;

    public Medallas() {

    }

    public Medallas(Deportistas codDeportista, Pruebas codPrueba, Date fechaMedallas, String puestoDeportista) {
        super();
        this.codDeportista = codDeportista;
        this.codPrueba = codPrueba;
        this.fechaMedallas = fechaMedallas;
        this.puestoDeportista = puestoDeportista;
    }

    public Deportistas getCodDeportista() {
        return codDeportista;
    }

    public void setCodDeportista(Deportistas codDeportista) {
        this.codDeportista = codDeportista;
    }

    public Pruebas getCodPrueba() {
        return codPrueba;
    }

    public void setCodPrueba(Pruebas codPrueba) {
        this.codPrueba = codPrueba;
    }

    public Date getFechaMedallas() {
        return fechaMedallas;
    }

    public void setFechaMedallas(Date fechaMedallas) {
        this.fechaMedallas = fechaMedallas;
    }

    public String getPuestoDeportista() {
        return puestoDeportista;
    }

    public void setPuestoDeportista(String puestoDeportista) {
        this.puestoDeportista = puestoDeportista;
    }

}
```

---

### Clase Pruebas

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pruebas")
public class Pruebas implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "codPrueba", columnDefinition = "CHAR(5)")
    private String codPrueba;

    @Column(name = "nombrePrueba", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(40)")
    private String nombrePrueba;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "codPrueba")
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private List<Medallas> medallas = new ArrayList<Medallas>();

    public Pruebas() {

    }

    public Pruebas(String codPrueba, String nombrePrueba, List<Medallas> medallas) {
        super();
        this.codPrueba = codPrueba;
        this.nombrePrueba = nombrePrueba;
        this.medallas = medallas;
    }

    public String getCodPrueba() {
        return codPrueba;
    }

    public void setCodPrueba(String codPrueba) {
        this.codPrueba = codPrueba;
    }

    public String getNombrePrueba() {
        return nombrePrueba;
    }

    public void setNombrePrueba(String nombrePrueba) {
        this.nombrePrueba = nombrePrueba;
    }

    public List<Medallas> getMedallas() {
        return medallas;
    }

    public void setMedallas(List<Medallas> medallas) {
        this.medallas = medallas;
    }

}
```

---

### Main

```
public class DataLoader {

    private static Session sesion;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        sesion = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        sesion.beginTransaction();

        // -------------------------//

        Paises pa1 = new Paises();
        Deportistas dep1 = new Deportistas();
        Licencias l1 = new Licencias();

        pa1.setCodPais("FGUI");
        pa1.setNombrePais("Alemania");
        pa1.getListDeportistas().add(dep1);

        dep1.setDniDeportista("81.198.381-D");
        dep1.setNombreDeportista("Oliver");
        dep1.setPais(pa1);
        dep1.setLicencia(l1);

        l1.setDeportista(dep1);
        l1.setLicencia("HJOWASH");
        l1.setNumIncidenciasLesiones(3);

        sesion.save(pa1);
        sesion.save(dep1);
        sesion.save(l1);

        // -------------------------//
        Paises pa2 = new Paises();
        Deportistas dep2 = new Deportistas();
        Licencias l2 = new Licencias();

        pa2.setCodPais("LKOP");
        pa2.setNombrePais("Francia");
        pa2.getListDeportistas().add(dep2);

        dep2.setDniDeportista("38.030.058-H");
        dep2.setNombreDeportista("Paul");
        dep2.setPais(pa2);
        dep2.setLicencia(l2);

        l2.setDeportista(dep2);
        l2.setLicencia("UNMLOPQ");
        l2.setNumIncidenciasLesiones(5);

        sesion.save(pa2);
        sesion.save(dep2);
        sesion.save(l2);
        // -------------------------//
        Paises pa3 = new Paises();
        Deportistas dep3 = new Deportistas();
        Licencias l3 = new Licencias();

        pa3.setCodPais("ASDF");
        pa3.setNombrePais("Holanda");
        pa3.getListDeportistas().add(dep3);

        dep3.setDniDeportista("92.146.963-Q");
        dep3.setNombreDeportista("Jean Claude");
        dep3.setPais(pa3);
        dep3.setLicencia(l3);

        l3.setDeportista(dep3);
        l3.setLicencia("HBNMOPQ");
        l3.setNumIncidenciasLesiones(2);

        sesion.save(pa3);
        sesion.save(dep3);
        sesion.save(l3);
        // -------------------------//
        Paises pa4 = new Paises();
        Deportistas dep4 = new Deportistas();
        // SIN LICENCIA

        pa4.setCodPais("UYRW");
        pa4.setNombrePais("Inglaterra");
        pa4.getListDeportistas().add(dep4);

        dep4.setDniDeportista("47.011.064-F");
        dep4.setNombreDeportista("John");
        dep4.setPais(pa4);

        sesion.save(pa4);
        sesion.save(dep4);
        // -------------------------//

        // PRUEBAS
        Pruebas pru1 = new Pruebas();
        pru1.setCodPrueba("HJKLQ");
        pru1.setNombrePrueba("Gimnacia");

        sesion.save(pru1);

        Pruebas pru2 = new Pruebas();
        pru2.setCodPrueba("GVBNW");
        pru2.setNombrePrueba("Boxeo");

        sesion.save(pru2);

        Pruebas pru3 = new Pruebas();
        pru3.setCodPrueba("VBNMO");
        pru3.setNombrePrueba("Futbol");

        sesion.save(pru3);

        // MEDALLAS
        Medallas m1 = new Medallas();
        m1.setCodDeportista(dep1);
        m1.setCodPrueba(pru1);
        m1.setFechaMedallas(Date.valueOf("1999-05-10"));
        m1.setPuestoDeportista("2");

        sesion.save(m1);
        // -------------------//
        Medallas m2 = new Medallas();
        m2.setCodDeportista(dep2);
        m2.setCodPrueba(pru2);
        m2.setFechaMedallas(Date.valueOf("2004-02-04"));
        m2.setPuestoDeportista("3");

        sesion.save(m2);
        // -------------------//

        Medallas m3 = new Medallas();
        m3.setCodDeportista(dep3);
        m3.setCodPrueba(pru3);
        m3.setFechaMedallas(Date.valueOf("2015-06-11"));
        m3.setPuestoDeportista("1");

        sesion.save(m3);
        // -------------------//

        sesion.getTransaction().commit();

        // Visualizar1();
        // Visualizar2();

        Visualizar3();
    }
```

---

### Método que realiza la consulta

Con este **método** lo que pretendo es pesarle el **código de el deportista** y que me devuelva todas las medallas que tiene ese deportista en las respectivas pruebas,en este caso lo leo desde teclado con un objeto de tipo **Scanner**.

```
public static void Visualizar3() {

        sesion.beginTransaction();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce el codigo de el deportista que quieras visualizar");
        int codDeportista = sc.nextInt();

        Query consulta = sesion.createQuery("from Medallas where codDeportista = :codDeportista");
        consulta.setParameter("codDeportista", codDeportista);

        List<Medallas> listdep = consulta.getResultList();

        for (Medallas medallas : listdep) {

            System.out.println("Puesto: " + medallas.getPuestoDeportista());
            System.out.println("Nombre De Prueba: " + 
             medallas.getCodPrueba().getNombrePrueba());
            System.out.println("Codigo De la prueba: " + 
            medallas.getCodPrueba().getCodPrueba());
            System.out.println("Fecha medalla: " + 
           medallas.getFechaMedallas());
        }

        sesion.getTransaction().commit();

    }
```

---

Lo curioso es que haciéndolo la asignación de el parámetro como la estoy haciendo,tengo entendido que es la forma correcta de hacerlo,me esta saltando una excepción,pero si le especifico el parámetro directamente concatenandolo al **String** de la consulta si devuelve el valor deseado como muestro aquí.

```
sesion.beginTransaction();

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Introduce el codigo de el deportista que quieras visualizar");
int codDeportista = sc.nextInt();

Query consulta = sesion.createQuery("from Medallas where codDeportista ="+ codDeportista);
consulta.setParameter("codDeportista", codDeportista);
```

---

De esta forma si me muestra el resultado deseado como se ve a continuación,aunque se que no es una buena practica por temas de seguridad.
[image: Resultado deseado pero concatenando directamente]

### Traza del error

```
Introduce el codigo de el deportista que quieras visualizar
2
nov 26, 2017 8:47:07 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Hibernate: select medallas0_.fechaMedallas as fechaMed1_2_, medallas0_.codPrueba as codPrueb3_2_, medallas0_.codDeportista as codDepor4_2_, medallas0_.puestoDeportista as puestoDe2_2_ from medallas medallas0_ where medallas0_.codDeportista=?
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer proyecto.Deportistas.codDeportista] by reflection for persistent property [proyecto.Deportistas#codDeportista] : 2
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    at main.DataLoader.Visualizar3(DataLoader.java:248)
    at main.DataLoader.main(DataLoader.java:160)
Caused by: org.hibernate.property.access.spi.PropertyAccessException: Error accessing field [private java.lang.Integer proyecto.Deportistas.codDeportista] by reflection for persistent property [proyecto.Deportistas#codDeportista] : 2
    at org.hibernate.property.access.spi.GetterFieldImpl.get(GetterFieldImpl.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4735)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.isTransient(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4435)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.isTransient(ForeignKeys.java:226)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:462)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.param.NamedParameterSpecification.bind(NamedParameterSpecification.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.bindParameterValues(QueryLoader.java:628)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2001)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1915)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:938)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:384)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1490)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1445)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Integer field proyecto.Deportistas.codDeportista to java.lang.Integer
```

---

Por ultimo agradecer cualquier tipo de ayuda o consejo por parte de la comunidad,un saludo.

Comment: ¿Puedes probar usando `consulta.setInteger("codDeportista", codDeportista);`? Segun Javadoc, con `setParameter` Hibernate intenta inferir el tipo del parámetro, e igual por ahí viene el problema, aunque no estoy muy seguro...

Comment: Lo que me dice si lo intento hacer de esa forma es que SetInteger() esta deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias de probar con:

```
 Query consulta = sesion.createSQLQuery("SELECT * from Medallas where codDeportista =:codDeportista");
consulta.setParameter("codDeportista", codDeportista);
```

consulta.list();

Esta sintaxis deberia de funcionarte y responder a tu cuestion.

Comment: De esta manera no me deja,me sale que esta manera esta Deprecated

Comment: @Ricki que método te dice que esta deprecated ?

Comment: Parece ser que en las nuevas versiones de **Hibernate (5.xxx)**,debería utilizar la función ` consulta.setParameter("codDeportista", codDeportista);` entiendo que infiere el tipo del dato que le estas pasando por el parámetro,en este caso un entero. @Marcos Pérez la Query en si no cambia lo que parece ser que esta es la forma de pasarle parametros,gracias por las sugerencia!